# Find Javascript array length without deleted items

Tags: javascript, arrays

Just a simple question that I can't seem to find the answer to.

> myarray.length()

The above will return the length including deleted items. How do I get the length without deleted items? Thanks

EDIT:

Thanks for the answers. I am deleting by writing 'delete myarray[0]' and this works well. Other sections of the script rely on the length() method to return the length including deletes. The splice method looks like what I want, so I'll try this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that you are deleting your array elements by using the [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/delete_Operator).

This operator removes the element at the index you specify, but the array length is not affected, for example:

```
var a = [1,2,3];

delete a[0];

console.log(a); // results in [undefined, 2, 3]
```

If you want to delete the elements and shift the indexes, you can use the [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function:

```
var a = [1,2,3];

a.splice(0,1);

console.log(a); // [2, 3]
```

You could implement a simple function to remove elements in a given index:

```
Array.prototype.removeAt = function (index) {
  this.splice(index,1);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you do want to use sparse arrays (totally legitimate) but want to count the number of defined elements, you can just use `reduce()`, for example:

```
var arr = [1, 2, undefined, 3, undefined, undefined, 4];
arr.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return typeof curr !== "undefined" ? prev+1 : prev;
}, 0); // evaluates to 4
```

`reduce()` is supported by all modern browsers, IE9+. For older browsers there's a polyfill and more info over at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: This worked for me since I needed to maintain the indexes of my array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **for..in loop**, which ommits deleted items.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
delete a[0];
delete a[1];

for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){}
console.log(i); //5

var j=0;
for(var i in a){j++;}
console.log(j); //3
```

Comment: This can be thousands of times faster than the reducer approach suggested by tobek. https://jsperf.com/length-of-sparse-array/1

Answer (score 1):

John Resig (author of jQuery) wrote a function that (really) removes items from an array in Javascript.  If you use this function instead of the delete operator, you should get an accurate count from the array after the deletion.

http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/

Comment: Do you know why he did that? It seems to be redundant, performing worse than the standard built-in splice method.

Comment: The method is comprehensive; it uses Splice, but it does some other things also.